# Should I migrate my firebase database to firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project with a firebase database and it works fine tell now.
Should I migrate my firebase database to firestore database?
Are advantages deserve the effort to build a new database because up to my knowledge there is no available way to migrate the database automatically tell now.

Comment: It's not mandatory to migrate to Firestore, but read this article and decide which is better for you https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore?authuser=2

Answer (score 2):

Firestore is currently in beta (meaning its API could change under your feet), so I would recommend against migrating until it is full-fledged.

Furthermore, there is a difference when it comes to pricing. In Firestore, you're charged for read/write/delete + storage. In Firebase, you are only charged for storage.

You can find a more [detailed breakdown here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore).

Comment: "In Firebase, you are only charged for storage.". If only this was true...